# Getting speed value from WP8 Geolocator when not moving

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, geolocation

I'm using the Geolocator class from WP8 to built a small app that displays the current speed. I have set the Accuracy to High and MovementThreshold to 0.1 meters. At the moment, I'm using the PositionChanged event of the geolocator to get the speed while moving.

The problem is, that when I stop moving, there is no PositionChanged event fired, and thus the speed is most of the time not 0 when it should be 0. Sometimes it works, sometimes not, I guess it has something to do with stopping somewhere in between the threshold.

Another posibility I tried, is not using PositionChanged and polling the current position with GetGeopositionAsync every second using a timer to update the speed. This seems to work better but I guess that this is the more power consumptional method as I am getting the position no matter if it's neccessary or not.

So what is the best way to get the current speed, no matter if moving or not? Can it even be done with PositionChanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no ideal solution for you.

In your case, I would go with a DispatcherTimer that would fire every second (for example).
You could use a timer as you mentioned, but instead of calling GetGeopositionAsync everytime, you can use the Geolocator instance to get current speed.

I guess speed doesn't only update when PositionChanged is fired so, that way, you could get an updated speed without consuming resources with GetGeopositionAsync.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I also think using a timer is the best way, but how do you get the current speed from the Geolocator instance? There does not seem to be a current position or current speed property in this class, so I think i have to use GetGeopositionAsync.

I additionally tried using the Report Interval Property of the Geolocator to force reporting the current position, but that works even worse, because the geolocator does not really report the position in the given time interval.

Comment: You are right. I can't see no way to get geolocator position without using GetGeopositionAsync. I'll try to think of another way to help you, but right now I can't think of anything.